# Find the intersection of linear span with a coordinate subspace $x_2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the intersection of the linear span of $\langle~1,1,1~\rangle$ and $\langle~0,1,-1,~\rangle$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the coordinate subspace $x_2 = 0$. Exhibit this intersection as a linear span.

- Does the coordinate subspace mean any 3d vector such that we have $(x_1, 0, x_3)$ for any vector?
- With two scalars of $1$ and $-1$, then one of the vectors in the linear span would be

$$ 
(1)\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + 
 (-1)\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{pmatrix} 
$$

Is this the correct way to show the intersection as a linear span?

Comment: you need to work with a general linear combination with coefficients $k_1$ and $k_2$. Since $x_2 = 0$, you will get $k_1 = -k_2$, and this defined your solution which must be a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the subspace with $x_2= 0$ is the set or all vectors of the form $\left<x_1, 0, x_3\right>$.  The subspace spanned by {<1, 1, 1>, <0, 1, -1>} is the set of all vectors of the form $a\left<1, 1, 1\right>+ b\left<0, 1, -1\right>= \left<a, a+b, a-b\right>$.  A vector in the intersection of those must satisfy $x_1= a$, $x_3= a-b$, and $a+ b= 0$.  From the last equation, $b= -a$.  Then $x_3= a-b= 2a$ so $\left<x_1, 0, x_3\right>= \left< a, 0, 2a\right>= a\left<1, 0, 2\right>$.  The intersection of the two subspaces is the one-dimensional subspace spanned by $\left<1, 0, 2\right>$.

Answer (score 1):

Any vector in 
$$\textsf{W}_1 = \operatorname{span}\left( \left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} ,
\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} 
\right\} \right)$$
is in the form
$$ t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + s \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} t \\ t+s \\ t-s \end{pmatrix}$$
for some real numbers $s$ and $t$.
Now, consider the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ :
$$\textsf{W}_2= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3: \, x_2 =0\right\}$$
Then, the intersection of both subspaces it consists of all those vectors in $\textsf{W}_1$ such that its second entry is zero. That is, the set $\textsf{W}_1 \cap \textsf{W}_2$ is given by
$$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} t \\ t+s \\ t-s \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3: \, t+s=0 \right\} =\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} t \\ t+s \\ t-s \end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^3: \, s=-t \right\}
=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} t \\ 0 \\ 2t \end{pmatrix}: \, t\in \mathbb{R}\right\}
=\left\{t \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}: \, t\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
It follows that
$$\textsf{W}_1 \cap \textsf{W}_2 = \operatorname{span} \left( \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \right)$$